# Making inserting a single character in Vim an atomic operation

Tags: vim

I've long used this very useful shortcut in vim:

```
nmap <space> i <esc>r
```

this means that if I press <kbd>space</kbd><kbd>f</kbd>, for example, it will insert a single character `f` at the given position.

unfortunately, however, this is not atomic, ie, if I press <kbd>space</kbd><kbd>f</kbd> and then navigate somewhere else, then press <kbd>.</kbd>, I get the equivalent of <kbd>r</kbd><kbd>f</kbd>, not <kbd>space</kbd><kbd>f</kbd>.

all this makes sense, but here's the question: is there a way of making this atomic, so that <kbd>.</kbd> will repeat the 'insert character' operation, and so that undo etc all treat it as one operation, too?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Awesome! Michael's answer pointed me to the plugin I needed to finish my plugin, which can now do what you want - I had been trying to figure out how to do this for ages!

**1)** Install [Tim Pope's plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2136)

**2)** Install [my plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2810)

**3)** Add a mapping to your `.vimrc`:

```
nnoremap <space> :<C-U>call InsertChar#insert(v:count1)<CR>
```

Comment: this is much more complicated than I was expecting, but does make the cursor red (which is a great touch), does allow cancellation with escape, and may just be what I use from here on in...

Comment: I only discovered this today, but I still comment want to say - this is going to be life-changing! Thank you!

Answer (score 8):

Does this work for you?

```
noremap <silent> <space> :exe "normal i".nr2char(getchar())<CR>
```

Comment: It's good, and definitely one possible solution. A disadvantage of this approach is that the cursor disappears when you press space, so you lose track of where you're inserting the character. @too much php's approach is much more complicated, but does have the advantage of leaving the cursor in place.

Comment: If you do quick insertions the lack of cursor isn't that annoing.

Comment: This is great! I used `K` which is unbound, uses the same `i` finger, and Kim starts with K.  I believe this is how the original developers mapped keys.

Answer (score 3):

You might want to have a look at this plugin script. It may be possible to configure your map so it can be supported. Read the supporting docs

http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2136

Comment: thanks a lot for this. it looks like @too much php's approach is pretty good, and it's based on this.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry I can't provide a specific answer to your problem but I will note that I tend to use the <kbd>.</kbd> key when I have to reproduce quite a lot of commands (e.g. I want to insert <kbd>f</kbd> 5 or more times).

If that is the case here, I don't think the saving of using your macro is worth it. You save one keystroke by using your macro rather than <kbd>i</kbd><kbd>f</kbd><kbd>esc</kbd> and that operation *is* atomic so you could then <kbd>.</kbd> to your heart's content.

I would just use the non-macro version if I know I want to repeat it a lot.

<kbd>P.S. You know I'm starting to like the <kbd> tag quite a bit :-)</kbd>

Comment: absolutely, and this is my current behaviour - but using this shortcut is so convenient I want to make it possible to use it all the time. it's less about saving keys, and more about consistency :)

Comment: +1 for random postscript (which I'm assuming isn't mocking me :))

Comment: No, I've actually never used it before, I've tended to use the blockquoting markup, but kbd is much better for keys.