# What is correct usage to go around vim missing "insert one char" command?

Tags: vim, insert

This is possibly not a good question for SO, but it's been bugging me for *years*, and Google didn't know, so let's give it a shot, as it does affect my programming work on weekly basis:

I often find myself in situation where one char is missing, like "=" instead of "==", a missing space, surrounding something with quotes/brackets, etc.

**So, why doesn't *vim* have a proper command to insert a single character?** By proper I mean, supports count and repeating with `.`.

What is the rationale, and what is the correct usage pattern that I am missing, which makes this feature unnecessary? I seem to need the all the time, so there must be some reason it has not been added to original *vi* already.

I know adding a simple basic keybinding like `:nmap <Space> i_<Esc>r` is easy enough, but when doing just a quick edit in a new environment, that's rather inconvenient, and this simple version does not work quite properly anyway.

PS. If there in fact is a *default* binding to insert just one char with *total two* keystrokes and remain in command mode, similar to `r` to replace one char with two keystrokes, I promise a bounty of 100 to the first answer which tells me what it is.

Comment: What do you mean by *I know adding a simple basic keybinding like :nmap <Space> i_<Esc>r is easy enough, but when doing just a quick edit in a new environment, that's rather inconvenient* ? Dont you use .vimrc ?

Comment: @Zaffy No, I don't. I don't use much vim, and when I do use it, it's often the first time I've logged into that system, possibly an embedded system, and often it's not practical to import a custom .vimrc. And when you often use vim without .vimrc, then it'd be double annoying if I sometimes had some features, then sometimes did not.

Comment: You dont need to import it. Vim does this automatically.

Comment: `By proper I mean, supports count and repeating with .` it works with my vim, strange. :)  you insert a "x" `ix<esc>` then you type `100.` you got 100x inserted. why you said vim doesn't support it? or I understood you wrong?

Comment: @Kent did you do that `nmap` in question? At least for me, after that `<space> X .` inserts X, but then `.` does not insert another, it just replaces the X with X. And `5 <space> X` inserts 4 underscores and one X.

Comment: I don't know why it is like that, but [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1557893/making-inserting-a-single-character-in-vim-an-atomic-operation) is how you correct it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*No.* There's no default keybinding for that (do `:viusage` for a complete list of normal mode commands).

If you want to know why, you'll have to ask Bram Moolenaar or Bill Joy, I'm afraid.

But here is an idea: `r` and `s` work on the character under the cursor. What they do is fairly limited and one dimensional but how would your command work?

Would it work like `i`, inserting that single character *before* the current character or would it work like `a`, inserting that single character *after* the current character?

Because "inserting text" can happen *before* or *after* the current character, we have `i` and `a` and, rather obviously, we need *two* commands for quickly inserting a single character.

Which makes the problem a little more complicated.

What keys should we use since all the alphabetical keys are already taken? `<C-something>`? `<C-i>` is taken, and `<C-a>` is also taken. `<C-S-i>` and `<C-S-a>` are both non-practical and not guaranteed to work everywhere so what? `<M-something>`? It won't work everywhere as well. Maybe a two-characters mapping? But which one and following what mnemonic logic?

Comment: I agree, and anything that uses a modifier key for me is almost as inefficient as typing two unmodified keys.

Comment: For logical behaviour, I'd go for "for next keystoke, act as if vi was in insert mode, with visual cursor in the position it is now shown", that nicely removes ambiguity between insert before/after, I think. Also, today `<space>` seems to be common char to remap to that functionality, but I'm not qualified to estimate what would have been good key to choose when *vi* was new.

Comment: Anyway, I assume your first paragraph is the correct answer, so accepting :)

Comment: Continuing my previous comment: Actually, `ctrl-o` could (should!) be symmetrical: in insert mode enter one normal mode command, in normal mode enter one insert mode keystroke.

Comment: You are still going forward, acting like `a` by default which would inevitably lead someone asking "But, why not *before* the cursor?". If you want to turn the `=` under your cursor into a `+=` you would still need `i+<Esc>`. That and `<C-o>` is already taken for a very important function.

Comment: @romainl `i+<Esc>` or more likely `<X>+` followed by generic cursor movement where <X> is the new insert-1 binding. Yes, `<C-o>` looks like it has an important function, but moving that would perhaps be less of on issue, than taking over many other suitable keys. I as a very casual vim user see great value on both "stay in normal mode" ideal(?) of vim ("insert one character without actually entering insert mode" would help that), as well as consistency (symmetry is a form of consistency). But, it's rather useless to discuss this in SO comments, so I think I'll leave this at that.

Answer (score 7):

To me, <kbd>i</kbd> <kbd><Char></kbd> <kbd>Esc</kbd> (3 keystrokes without modifier keys) is pretty short and built-in. You've already discovered custom mappings that reduce that to two keystrokes; I also started with yours and over time made it more advanced to suit my needs, and added mapping variants to insert a single space at or after the cursor position.

Presumably, there's no built-in command because the key space (especially for single unshifted keys) is *very* limited, this one doesn't justify such prime space, and any multi-key alternative (like the Vim ones that start with `g`) would be worthless in terms of efficiency.

Comment: Yes, I do that 3 keystrokes now, but since `Esc` key is pretty far, and requires moving the entire hand (YMMV depending on your hand size), it feels like twice the effort of typing 2-keystroke `r <char>`.

Comment: `<Esc>` shouldn't be an issue; many Vi(m) users tweak their keyboard (swapping Caps Lock with either Esc or Ctrl) and/or use <C-[>, which is the same as Esc.

Comment: That keyboard mapping would be nice for other uses too and not just vi, if only I used just one computer system with one OS... Ah, a single keyboard layout stored behind a http URL, and then driver/tool for all OSes to download and apply it, preferably without admin privileges.

Comment: Yes, it's usually a system-wide remapping, especially when it involved Caps Lock. Usually, the number of physical systems you sit in front of is rather limited, so it's only a matter of re-configuring your personal devices.

Answer (score 2):

I also struggled with this question and I found somewhere on the internet (I can't remember where) someone who did this:

`:nnoremap s :exec "normal i".nr2char(getchar())."\e"<CR>`

It is not perfect because it doesn't support count but it can be repeated with `.` I use that now so maybe other users will be satisfied with that too.